# Jobs message "read" status is ambiguous

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface

I have a couple of messages in my Jobs Inbox. Although apparently I have successfully marked them both "read", the sender's name still appears in bold type, and the only indication that they're read is that the *date*, which is off on the right, is no longer bold.

It would be very helpful to have markedly more contrast between read and unread messages.

Comment: Fair point, I'll fix this tomorrow as well. Although we do change the background colour of the message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report, it's just been pushed to prod.